# dhcpcd overwrites NetworkManager's /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, networkmanager

I have an Archlinux machine. The IP is set to a fixed value, configured via the *NetworkManager*. When I tell the NetworkManager to connect with this configuration it successfully updates my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mydomain
nameserver 10.123.255.254
```

Fine. But after some minutes the *dhcpcd* overwrites it, and it finally looks like this:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
nameserver 192.168.0.254
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now I have two problems: First, I don't know, why dhcpcd updates the file. I don't even know why it is running, because I have a fixed IP. Furthermore I disabled it using `systemctl stop dhcpcd && systemctl disable dhcpcd`.

My other problem is, I don't know where these nameserver addresses come from. These are the old values of my old DHCP-Server, but this server isn't available anymore. I already sniffed with wireshark for packets containing this configuration but I couldn't find anything that looked like this. **UPDATE: this part is solved, see below**

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT:** Maybe you want to see my NetworkManager connection details:

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

[connection]
id=fixed
uuid=12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-012345abcdef
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1396699414

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=10.123.255.254;
dns-search=ait;
address1=10.123.44.44/16,10.123.255.254
```

**UPDATE 2014-05-16:**

The problem appeared again. But today I saw the following two warnings in the NetworkManager log:

```
NetworkManager[423]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
NetworkManager[423]: <warn> Dispatcher failed: (32) Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Maybe that helps?

I found out where the nameserver addresses came from: They were configured in `/etc/resolv.conf.tail`.

Comment: I also noticed, that our DHCP Server has a lease for my computer, even if my computer does not use it. Seems that some service on my computer requests an IP, but I don't want it...

Answer (score 0):

Just what ArchLinux-Forum members use to pray almost every time a user asks weird stuff: *"Is your system up to date?"*.

No. My system wasn't up to date. Just ran `pacman -Syyu`, rebooted and wohoo! Now it runs as expected.

So, note to myself: always update your system when something's weird! :-)

**UPDATE** Too bad. Network Manager just started doing it again, so for me, **this (my own) answer is now invalid**.